# How to synchronize data between server nodes?

Tags: java, synchronization, nodes

I have a Java EE application which is clustered on two WebSphere V7 nodes. If a client changes data which is persisted to a database on node 1, I want to make sure that the data is updated immediately on node 2 as well.

I considered using an EJB timer service which does a check on the database every few minutes. But what can I do if I want to have the update to be performed on-time, without any delay on node 2 and not setting the interval to one second or so? Well I could call a servlet on node 2 from node 1 and trigger the update this way. But in this case my application has to know the http addresses of all nodes. This is not what I want. Any other suggestions?

Is there a best practice for synchronizing data changes between server nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using WebSphere I'd recommend using the [DistributedMap](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v5r1//index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wasee.doc/info/ee/ae/tdyn_distmap.html) that is built into WAS.

Comment: Hmm.. sounds promising. But I did not read anything about synchronizing between server nodes. It seems it is more like a common cache for JSPs and servlet outputs? Do you have more information / experiences?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Jboss JGroups which offers different synchronization methods. 
http://www.jgroups.org/

Comment: Well I would rather use a more lightweight solution for my problem - without using additional jars or frameworks if possible.

Comment: I see. However the jgroups document offers some patterns which might be usefull even if you do not use the Jgroups implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your two WebSphere nodes talk to the same database and you haven't added any form of caching then the data will be available as soon as Node 2 run a SQL query on the database.

Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: The thing is I'm loading master data at application startup into a singleton POJO. After the initialization all requests use the singleton to access this data in order to avoid additional (and long running) master data database access. But because the application is clustered I unfortunalety have two singletons (one on every node) which I have to keep synchronized somehow...